Пробежка по двум циклам одновременно в питон
Хочу спросить существует ли функционал пробежки сразу по двум листам с данными в питон.
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [6, 3, 8]

Нужно например сложить числа 1 и 6, 2 и 3, 3 и 8.

функция zip(a, b)

Если размеры одинаковые, то в обычном цикле это можно легко сделать. Если размеры разные, надо понять что делать и тоже через цикл можно. Просто внутри цикла обращайтесь к нужным вам индексам

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [6, 3, 8]
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    print(i+j)


7
5
11

Или через map()
c=list(map(lambda i,j:i+j,a,b))
print(c)


[7, 5, 11]


При условии, что длины списков одинаковые, можно сделать в цикле for
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [6, 3, 8]

for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i] + b[i])

# вывод:
7
5
11

len() вернет длину списка, а range() последовательность чисел(в нашем случае от 0 до длины массива -)

Можно и так, но похоже с zip удобнее

@Serviswriter Смотрите сами. Для маленьких списков и таких задач наверне разницы нет, а вот на больших объемах надо смотреть производительность, т.к. zip сначала пробежит по спискам, сформирует новый список, а затем вы в финальном списке будете выполнять операции. В простом for операций доступа к начальным спискам меньше. Однако знать о существовании разных вариантов доступа/преобразовани и фукнций работы со списками полезно

Понял. Спасибо. У меня ситуация такова - пробежка по двум двумерным массивам из трёх элементов по три элемента, думаю я всёже использую zip, но в задачах, где будет требоваться скорость буду использовать ваш вариант.

zip  в Питоне ленивый, так что никуда он заранее не побежит 3.3 3.12

@SwaD "Однако знать о существовании разных вариантов доступа/преобразовани и фукнций работы со списками полезно" - совершенно верно, а то будешь в интернете чепуху гнать про "zip сначала пробежит по спискам, сформирует новый список"

@AlexanderPavlov Интересно. Спасибо! Потестировал. zip на 10млн списке работает на +/- 250 мс быстрее, чем досуп напрямую(мой вариант). Во всех тестах zip победил. Где то в моем варианте теряется некая константа времени ->(range(len), zip) 10млн 0:00:01.416010 0:00:01.140998, 100млн 0:00:14.425077 0:00:11.942072, 1млн 0:00:00.143997 0:00:00.112009 - визуально видно разницу в +/- 20%. Так что каюсь, возвращаю свои слова назад

@SwaD Питон как-то оптимизирует доступ к элементам списков, поэтому встроенные методы перебора обычно лучше, чем "ручная" индексация по спискам. Грубо говоря, при "ручной" индексации питону нужно полноценный объект держать для переменной i и работать с ним, а при использовании zip это не нужно, вот и экономия.
